# Triangle-like Slider in React js and MUI

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui, jsx

I want to create price control using react js and MUI like this below image , but I am facing issue on how to do this.

[image: example of slider]

I have tried finding libraries or any solution at online platforms but haven't found any solution

Comment: The native HTML5 range input is somewhat customizable. See for example this [blog post](https://blog.logrocket.com/creating-custom-css-range-slider-javascript-upgrades/). The hard part about this is the triangle background and the (I assume?) scaling of the slider-thumb.

Comment: Thanks, for your solution, yes I tried customizing the html5 range input before but it didn't provided the expected result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of the box, MUI doesn't have a styled slider similar to what you're looking for, but with some creative styling and a little bit of math, you can extend the Ranged [`MuiSlider`](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-slider/#range-slider) to get close to what you want.

This is a ***quick and dirty (incomplete) example***, but should work as a starting point for you, should you choose to go with MUI.

Basically, it's the out-of-the-box slider, but I've used a CSS [`clip-path`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path) to shape the rail (`.MuiSlider-rail`) [as a triangle (actually polygon)](https://codepen.io/stoumann/full/abZxoOM) with a dynamic [`linear-gradient`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient) (with sharp transitions) to emulate the grey-to-orange-to-grey background effect. I also hid the track (`.MuiSlider-track`) as it wasn't needed for this implementation.

Lastly, is some poor math (I'll leave that for you to fix, if you'd like ) to re-position/re-size the thumbs based on their respective values.

```
      <Slider
        getAriaLabel={() => "Price range"}
        value={value}
        onChange={handleChange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
        marks={marks}
        step={50}
        sx={{
          // Style the rail as a triangle
          "& .MuiSlider-rail": {
            height: "20px",
            borderRadius: 0,
            clipPath: "polygon(0% 75%,100% 0%,100% 100%,0% 100%)",
            background: `linear-gradient(90deg, #ccc ${start}%, #F74 ${start}%, #F74 ${end}%, #ccc ${end}%)`,
            opacity: 1
          },
          // Hide the track (not needed)
          "& .MuiSlider-track": {
            display: "none"
          },
          // You can do some of this in the theme, but I added it here for reference
          "& .MuiSlider-thumb": {
            top: "70%",
            backgroundColor: "#F74",
            border: "4px solid #fff",
            boxShadow:
              "0px 3px 1px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.2), 0px 2px 2px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.14), 0px 1px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.12)",
            "&:before": {
              boxShadow: "none"
            }
          },
          // Re-size/position thumbs individually based on their values
          "& [data-index='0']:not(.MuiSlider-markLabel)": {
            // This `top` math is gross, but I needed to shift the thumbs up based on value -- could be improved
            top: `${70 - start / 5}%`,
            width: `calc(20px + ${0.2 * start}px)`,
            height: `calc(20px + ${0.2 * start}px)`
          },
          "& [data-index='1']:not(.MuiSlider-markLabel)": {
            // This `top` math is gross, but I needed to shift the thumbs up based on value -- could be improved
            top: `${70 - end / 5}%`,
            width: `calc(20px + ${0.2 * end}px)`,
            height: `calc(20px + ${0.2 * end}px)`
          },
          "& .MuiSlider-markLabel": {
            marginTop: "0.75rem",
            color: "#c0c0c0",
            "&.MuiSlider-markLabelActive": {
              color: "#F74"
            }
          },
          "& .MuiSlider-mark": {
            display: "none"
          }
        }}
      />
```

**Result:**

[image: example slider output]

**Working CodeSandbox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/rough-wildflower-6qfsfk?file=/demo.tsx:759-2218